# Cisco ASA, Windows Server 08, PPTP/GRE issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, cisco, nat, cisco-asa, pptp

I am at the end of my rope on this one.  I am trying to simply forward `pptp/gre` through a Cisco ASA to my Windows server.  Here is what I have done:

Access Rules:

```
OUTSIDE
____________________________________________________________________________
|   Source     |    Destination   |   Service     |    Action    |   Hits  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  any         |  outside         | protocol -gre |  permit      |  0      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  any         |  outside         | tcp - pptp    |  permit      |  5      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have the identical above set as ACL too ...

My NAT rule:

```
NAT RULE
_______________________________________________________________________________
|        |                 Original           |        Translated             |
|  Type  |_____________________________________________________________________
|        |    Source  | Destination | Service | Interface | Address | Service |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| static | 10.1.10.11 |             | pptp    | outside   | outside | pptp    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also in my `global_policy` I am inspecting `pptp`.  Here is my current running config:

Result of the command: "show run"

```
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.2(5) 
!
hostname DTS-ASA
enable password xxxxxxxxxxxxx
passwd xxxxxxxxxxx
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.1.10.100 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 74.xx.xx.225 255.255.255.248 
!
ftp mode passive
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1
 network-object 10.xx.xx.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.xx.xx.0 255.255.255.0
access-list outside_access_in extended permit icmp any any 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit gre any interface outside 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any interface outside eq pptp 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.xx.xx.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.xx.xx.0 255.255.255.0 
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0
static (inside,outside) tcp interface pptp 10.1.10.11 pptp netmask 255.255.255.255 
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 74.xx.xx.230 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
http server enable
http 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_1_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs group5
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer 63.xx.xx.xx 
crypto map outside_map 1 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto isakmp enable inside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 10
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 20
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 30
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 40
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 50
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 60
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 70
 authentication crack
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 80
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 90
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 100
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 120
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 130
 authentication crack
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 140
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 150
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 170
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd dns xx.xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx.Xx
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 10.1.10.104-10.1.10.254 inside
dhcpd enable inside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
tunnel-group 63.xx.xx.xx type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 63.xx.xx.xx ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *****
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
  inspect pptp 
  inspect icmp 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:xxxxxxxxxxxx
: end
```

Is there anything wrong with the above configuration that would be blocking PPTP to the Windows server at 10.1.10.11?  I attempt to connect via WIndows 7 VPN client and get `ERROR 807: The network connection between your computer and the VPN server was interrupted`.  If you have resolution, please be as descriptive as possible, as I have taken the time to make my question as descriptive as possible.  Thank you.

Comment: Avoid posting the entire asa config. Just post the few snippets relevant. (It is unlikely anyone here on SF will look at something that long in detail, and the majority of it is not relevant to the question)

Comment: My reasoning is:  I have an issue, and that being said, I might be unaware of secondary configuration issues that might **cause** my issue, but may not be **directly** related.  --  So, more info = more tools for solving the issue ...  Besides that, from my experience, anyone familiar with the ASA unit can dig through the config fairly rapidly pulling out "relevant" bits.